# Who authenticates baseball paraphernalia?

Tags: baseball, mlb, collectibles

There is always a person at major league baseball games who authenticates certain items. A player's 1st hit or home run ball, a home run caught by a fan, a pitcher's 2,000th strike out, things like that.

Who determines which items are authenticated, and is that person hired by MLB, the ballpark, or whom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Off-duty law enforcement officers** working as independent contractors are assigned by *Authenticators, Inc.* for Major League Baseball Properties to authenticate autographs and game-used memorabilia at every Major League Baseball game. Only those items that an authenticator actually witnesses being signed or used in a game may be eligible for authentication under the [MLB Authentication Program](https://www.mlb.com/authentication).

Other Sources: [tokens-icons.com](https://tokens-icons.com/pages/mlb-authentication), [sportscollectorsdigest](http://www.sportscollectorsdigest.com/an-inside-look-at-the-major-league-baseball-authentication-program/).